Java Spring Security: How to make endpoint accessible for guests using annotations?
Let's say I have a project with Spring Security where all endpoints are available only for authenticated users. I want to make some endpoints accessible without authentication. I can easily find answers how to do this (1, 2, 3), but all this answers require me to add URLs of my endpoints into Spring Security configuration class. Like this:
.antMatchers("/my/long/url").permitAll()
Or similarly.
I don't like this approach for two reasons:

It will make my Spring Security configuration class really long and hardly readable.
It will "split" code of my endpoints in controllers and information about access requirements for them in different files.

Ideally I want to have some annotation to mark controller methods accessible by guests. Like this
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @NonSecured
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}


I know that there is method level security feature in Spring, but all examples I found explains how to add new access requirements to already existing ones. I could not find any examples which allows me to make endpoints accessible for guests.

Have you tried @Secured("permitAll") ?

At least in Spring Boot 3/Spring Security 6, it should be possible to create multiple SecurityFilters (security configurations), also in static inner classes of controllers.

@Yann39, I tried @Secured("permitAll"), but Spring still requires me to login

You need to make a SecurityFilterChain to permit access to endpoints for guests because the SecurityFilterChain is working in front of controllers. I think you need to design application endpoints for guests. First, make .requestMatchers("/api/guests/**").permitAll() in the security config. Second, create controller for guests with @Controller and @RequestMapping("/api/guests"). Lastly, make new endpoints in the above controller.

@Vaks OK that was just a guess, I have no code to test this at the moment, maybe also try @PermitAll (JSR-250), which may act differently. But I'm not sure, I think if you have .anyRequest().authenticated() in your global security, it might still restrict access to methods with @Secured("permitAll") or @PermitAll, in that case I guess you have to go with multiple security filters. Good luck.

What you call guests is what spring security calls anonymous users. You should be able to annotate endpoints to use the ROLE_ANONYMOUS as described here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/anonymous.html i dont have any code examples and there is way too little ingormation in the question to be able to produce somewhat of an example. Good luck

@Junhyunny, I don't want all guest-accessible endpoints to have /api/guests prefix and I don't want to move them in guest controller.
